# VS code is not running python

Tags: python

[I am veryy new in coding and wanted to get into it. So I downloaded VS code. But I tried to run a very simple python command and it does not let me. See the picture below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ebV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio code is not an IDE, it is a code editor, which means you cannot run nor debug code naturally, for that you would need to run it on the windows terminal, or install extra packages and dependencies. If youre new and just want to learn Python, i suggest starting with a python IDE like the standard one provided or something more advanced like Pycharm, and if you want to program on VsCode and in multiple languages, search some tutorials about how to compile and run code on the windows terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details about how you installed python from Microsoft Store, from anaconda or via its official page https://www.python.org/downloads/. Try running

```
python --version
```

or

```
python3 --version
```

If so you can run a python file from terminal. Assuming my file is called **test.py**

```
python test.py
```